# Why is == in Lua behaving like this?

Tags: printing, lua

In Lua interpreter when we type:

```
>print(1=="1") 
 false
```

Ok fine!

```
>print(false==true) 
 false
```

Ok fine!

```
>print(string==math) 
 false
```

Ok but why?

```
>print(function==nil) 
 stdin:1: '(' expected near '=='
```

I don't understand the working of == and ~=. please explain

Comment: why `string` should be equal to `math`? and `function` is keyword but not variable so `function == nil` has no sence at all.

Comment: `==` checks whether the arguments are equal. It's hard to explain where your understanding is wrong without knowing what you thought would happen. What makes you think `string==math` would give any result other than false? What did you expect to be the result of `print(function==nil)`?

Comment: @ChrisH that is the thing! string and math are a part of the standard library. so if string and math are false since they don't make any sense to be equal. Then function and nil should also be false , but it is not so. It throws an error instead!.

Comment: OK, I think I now understand what you're asking. I'll post an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @GouravDas string == match is a valid Lua expression. function == nil is not. That's why you get an error.

Comment: @GouravDas the answer from Piglet already says everything I would have, so I won't write mine any more because it would basically be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print(function==nil)
```

Gives you the error message:

> stdin:1: '(' expected near '=='

Because `function` is a keyword that is used to define a function variable. That keyword is expected to be used in a certain syntax. `function` on its own is not a valid Lua expression and can therefor not be used as one. Lua is telling you that you wrote something
 it cannot interpret and that it usually would expect `function` to be followed by `(`.

Please read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11
and https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4 and https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.5

and anything else :)

string and math are both Lua standard libraries. string and math are two different Lua tables. Hence they cannot be the same and therefor the expression string == math is false.

From https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4:

> The basic expressions in Lua are the following:
>
> exp ::= prefixexp
>
> exp ::= nil | false | true
>
> exp ::= Numeral
>
> exp ::= LiteralString
>
> exp ::= functiondef
>
> exp ::= tableconstructor
>
> exp ::= ‘...’
>
> exp ::= exp binop exp
>
> exp ::= unop exp
>
> prefixexp ::= var | functioncall | ‘(’ exp ‘)’

As you see only the Lua keywords nil, false and true are expressions on their own. Other keywords are not.

math and string are no Lua keywords at all. They are variables of type table. And variables are expressions as well. That's why you don't get an error for `math == string`

Questions like that are best answered by reading Lua's reference manual and Programming in Lua.

https://www.lua.org/docs.html

I don't say that you should know everything that is in there befor you start. But knowing the very basics will accelerate your learning experience and your understanding a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Without writing the keyword function, do like this

```
   function test()
      print('test')
  end
  print(test() == nil) -- prints true
```